# "Generic member" in a nontempered L-packet

Tags: rt.representation-theory, langlands-conjectures

It is a standard conjecture that there is a unique generic member in a tempered L-packet. Is there an analogue of this for non-tempered ones, namely does one expect that there is a unique "most generic" member inside a non-tempered L-packet in some sense? This question basically comes from my lack of ability to pin down a reference on a structure of nontempered L-packets, so any reference on this would be highly appreciated.